# Convert data frame column values into multiple yaml file

Tags: r, yaml

I have a data frame which is similar to:

```r
df <- data.frame(State = c("A", "B"),
                 Cust_Age = c(25, 50),
                 City = c("Aa", "Bb"))
```

I want the values of each row to be converted into different yaml file.

I expect each file to contain this:

```yaml
State:
   type: string
   example: A
Cust_Age:
   type: number
   example: 25
City:
   type: string
   example: Aa
```

Similarly the second yaml file will contain values of second row of data frame.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide code blocks inline within ``` markers and __not__ as image. This increases your likelihood of getting answers tremendeously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `library(yaml)`. You need to cast your `data.frame` to a list structure first, which `yaml::as.yaml` can understand:

```r
library(yaml)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(State = c("A", "B"),
                 Cust_Age = c(25, 50),
                 City = c("Aa", "Bb"))
ys <- df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   group_map(function(x, y) {
      map(x, ~ list(type = case_when(is.factor(.x) | is.character(.x) ~ "string",
                                     is.numeric(.x) ~ "number", 
                                     is.logical(.x) ~ "logical", 
                                     TRUE ~ "unknown"),
                    example = .x)
      ) %>%
      as.yaml()
   })
 
cat(ys[[1L]])
# State:
#   type: string
#   example: A
# Cust_Age:
#   type: number
#   example: 25.0
# City:
#   type: string
#   example: Aa

cat(ys[[2L]])
# State:
#   type: string
#   example: B
# Cust_Age:
#   type: number
#   example: 50.0
# City:
#   type: string
#   example: Bb
```

If you expect other data types than `string` and `number` adapt your `case_when` accordingly (I added `logical`  as a hypothetical example).

Note that `as.yaml` (correctly)  transforms `25` to `25.0` because despite its appearance `25` ist **not** and integer. If you want `25` you should declare your numbers as integers by adding `L`:

```r
cat(as.yaml(list(example = 25)))
# example: 25.0
cat(as.yaml(list(example = 25L)))
# example: 25
```

Comment: How to save this list into different .yaml files ?

Comment: check [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/yaml/man/write_yaml.html) out

Comment: `iwalk(ys, ~ cat(.x, file = paste0("YAML_Row_", .y, ".yaml")))`